# java.lang.AssertionError: Response content

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot

I am trying to test a `UnitTest` but getting `java.lang.AssertionError: Response content`
 while running the test.
**My Logcat**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Response content
Expected: <[UserDTO [firstName=Ahmad, lastName=shahzad, userName=1, emailAddress=ahmad.shahzad@null], UserDTO [firstName=Jamshaid, lastName=iqbal, userName=2, emailAddress=jamshaid.ali@null], UserDTO [firstName=Waqas, lastName=Akram, userName=3, emailAddress=waqas.akram@null]]>
 but: was "[{\"firstName\":\"Ahmad\",\"lastName\":\"shahzad\",\"userName\":\"1\",\"emailAddress\":\"ahmad.shahzad@null\"},{\"firstName\":\"Jamshaid\",\"lastName\":\"iqbal\",\"userName\":\"2\",\"emailAddress\":\"jamshaid.ali@null\"},{\"firstName\":\"Waqas\",\"lastName\":\"Akram\",\"userName\":\"3\",\"emailAddress\":\"waqas.akram@null\"}]"
Expected :<[UserDTO [firstName=Ahmad, lastName=shahzad, userName=1, emailAddress=ahmad.shahzad@null], UserDTO [firstName=Jamshaid, lastName=iqbal, userName=2, emailAddress=jamshaid.ali@null], UserDTO [firstName=Waqas, lastName=Akram, userName=3, emailAddress=waqas.akram@null]]>
Actual   :"[{\"firstName\":\"Ahmad\",\"lastName\":\"shahzad\",\"userName\":\"1\",\"emailAddress\":\"ahmad.shahzad@null\"},{\"firstName\":\"Jamshaid\",\"lastName\":\"iqbal\",\"userName\":\"2\",\"emailAddress\":\"jamshaid.ali@null\"},{\"firstName\":\"Waqas\",\"lastName\":\"Akram\",\"userName\":\"3\",\"emailAddress\":\"waqas.akram@null\"}]"
```

```
at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.ContentResultMatchers.lambda$string$3(ContentResultMatchers.java:130)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:195)
```

**UnitTestCase Class**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class UnitTestAuth {
@Autowired
public MockMvc mvc;

@Test
public void getHello() throws Exception {
    mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/auth").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string(equalTo(new UserController().getUsers())));
}


}
```

**Controller Class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class UserController {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(UserController.class.getName());

@Value("${mail.domain ?: google.com}")
private static String mailDomain;

private List<UserDTO> users = Arrays.asList(new UserDTO("Ahmad", "shahzad", "1", "ahmad.shahzad@" + mailDomain),
        new UserDTO("Jamshaid", "iqbal", "2", "jamshaid.ali@" + mailDomain),
        new UserDTO("Waqas", "Akram", "3", "waqas.akram@" + mailDomain));


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public List<UserDTO> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "{userName}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public UserDTO getUserByUserName(@PathVariable("userName") String userName) {
    UserDTO userDtoToReturn = null;
    for (UserDTO currentUser : users) {
        if (currentUser.getUserName().equalsIgnoreCase(userName)) {
            userDtoToReturn = currentUser;
            if (LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.INFO)) {
                LOGGER.info(String.format("Found matching user: %s", userDtoToReturn.toString()));
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return userDtoToReturn;
}
}
```

> Problem:
>   I am unable to get how should I match those both string in order to get the test passed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `new UserController().getUsers())` returns a `List<UserDTO>` which you are trying to compare to the JSON string returned by call in context of mvc framework. That will obviously not work.

Comment: @AlanHay I know. But not finding a way to compare them both

Comment: show you MockMvcRequestBuilders configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `json()` instead of `string()` in your case as your response is converted to JSON internally. And use `ObjectMapper` from `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` to convert your response list to JSON.

```
@Test
public void getHello() throws Exception {
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(new UserController().getUsers());
    mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/auth").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().json(result));
}
```

EDIT : You can convert the List of objects to JSON using ObjectMapper.

Comment: `getUsers()` is returning a list. how is that supposed to change to JSON?

Comment: it resolved the error after adding [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.skyscreamer/jsonassert/1.5.0) dependency

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare the content string with an actual object as it is when its `toString()` method is invoked as seen here:

```
Expected: <[UserDTO [firstName=Ahmad, lastName=shahzad, userName=1, emailAddress=ahmad.shahzad@null], UserDTO [firstName=Jamshaid, lastName=iqbal, userName=2, emailAddress=jamshaid.ali@null], UserDTO [firstName=Waqas, lastName=Akram, userName=3, emailAddress=waqas.akram@null]]>
 but: was "[{\"firstName\":\"Ahmad\",\"lastName\":\"shahzad\",\"userName\":\"1\",\"emailAddress\":\"ahmad.shahzad@null\"},{\"firstName\":\"Jamshaid\",\"lastName\":\"iqbal\",\"userName\":\"2\",\"emailAddress\":\"jamshaid.ali@null\"},{\"firstName\":\"Waqas\",\"lastName\":\"Akram\",\"userName\":\"3\",\"emailAddress\":\"waqas.akram@null\"}]"
```

You have to parse each of the attributes in the content or use some kind of JSON parser to do it in bulk. Then compare each of the parsed attributes with the field of the User object.

Comment: how am I supposed to use JSON parser?

Comment: You have to figure it out. The point is, you cannot assert equals on a string and an actual object.toString().